# cannot implicitly convert type SananPos to Void

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtMagazaNo.Text != string.Empty && txtTerminalNo.Text != string.Empty && txtKullaniciAdı.Text != string.Empty &&
        txtSifre.Text != string.Empty && txtParola.Text != string.Empty && comboCompany.SelectedIndex > -1 && comboCompany.SelectedIndex > -1 && comboBank.SelectedIndex > -1 && DatePicker3.SelectedDate != null && LstTaskOfUsers.Items.Count > 0)
    {

        if (sanalPosList == null && txtMagazaNo.Text != string.Empty && txtTerminalNo.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            SanalPos SanalPosControl = SanalPos.InsertSanalPos(sanalPosList[comboCompany.SelectedIndex].Id, sanalPosList[comboBank.SelectedIndex].Id, txtMagazaNo.Text, txtTerminalNo.Text, txtKullaniciAdı.Text, txtParola.Text, txtSifre.Text, "", "", txtNot.Text, 1, DateTime.Now, "");
            if (sanalPosList == null)

                SanalPos.InsertSanalPos(sanalPosList[comboCompany.SelectedIndex].Id, sanalPosList[comboBank.SelectedIndex].Id, txtMagazaNo.Text, txtTerminalNo.Text, txtKullaniciAdı.Text,


                txtParola.Text, txtSifre.Text, "", "", txtNot.Text, 0, DateTime.Now, "");
            }

    }
```

Comment: Nice `if`s you have there

Comment: Stackoverflow is a **q** & a site. You forgot the **q**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly likely that this method:

```
SanalPos.InsertSanalPos();
```

Has a return type of `void`.

If you need it to return something you need to change the return type to `SanalPos` and return an object of the same type.